# How to reference a chart object on an MS Access subform?

Tags: ms-access

I have created a dozen different charts using the chart form wizard in Access (so each chart is really a separate form).  I have also set up a GUI that has the following nested form structure:

```
frmMain -> frmSubMain -> Child0 (a subform of frmSubMain)
```

I have a list box on frmSubMain that lists all the charts, and when a user selects one, I use VBA to change the Source Object of Child0 to the appropriate form for the selected chart.  (So in essence, a user can select the desired chart and it is presented.)

I am now trying to add a button to frmSubMain that will copy the currently selected chart to PowerPoint, but I am having trouble with the copy command and referencing the chart object.  The chart object on each of the forms is called OLEUnbound0, and here is what I've tried (I have the form name for the chart as a variable 'my_form'):

- Forms(my_form).OLEUnbound0.acOLECopy
- Me.Child0.OLEUnbound0.acOLECopy
- Me.Controls(my_form).OLEUnbound0.acOLECopy

Each gives a different error (for example, the second one gives the error "Method or data member not found").  Part of my confusion is that I have the form name but as a variable, and I'm not sure how to use that variable (since I can't use the standard Forms![frmMain]![frmSubMain]! etc.).  What is the syntax for using a variable to reference a subform?

Comment: You need to refer to both the child control (subform control) and the form contained before you reference an object, so `Me.NameOfSubformControl.Form.NameOfControl` NameOfSubformControl and NameOfControl have to be changed to your names, but you do not need to know the name of the form contained by the subform control, it is reference by the Form property of the control.

Comment: I'm not sure I translated this correctly, but I just tried Me.Child0.Form.OLEUnbound0.acOLECopy and got an object does not support this property error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Me.Child0.Form.OLEUnbound0.Action = acOLECopy
```

Comment: @Remou--I've been using this for a couple months and just noticed that when it copies charts, the chart data may be several weeks old.  I added in a requery on the form and control, and that didn't seem to help.  I tinkered with some of the forms, and at times that caused one of the charts (I'm using this in a loop to copy five charts) to be updated, but the others still show old data.  Maybe I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any insight on how this command works or thoughts on why I'd see this behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: I just played with it some more, and if I manually open the forms and then close them, and then run the code, it works fine.  Otherwise it seems as if it's somehow getting a cached version of the chart--would that even be possible?  And it seems that opening and closing the form from VBA doesn't work to resolve the problem--it has to be manually opened.

Comment: Yes, that could be possible with a chart, however, opening the form with VBA should work, I have not tested, but I am guessing you need a requery or recalc. There is also another oddity - you may need to minimize and maximize the form to get it to display properly.

Comment: @Remou-Let me know if I need to start a new post, but I've tried everything and can't get it to work. I've tried opening each form with VBA, then later in the subroutine doing the copy/paste--still the same problem. I tried opening all forms with VBA, adding a 10 second delay, then closing all forms, then doing the copy/paste--same problem. I tried opening each form, doing a 10 second delay after each open--same problem. (Also did min, max, and requery on the form in all these trials.) One note, when I open the form with VBA, I never see the chart...just white space where the object is.